# How to declare WAF dependency of test script on built program?

Tags: build, dependencies, waf

I am struggling to find the correct way to define the dependency of a test script
on a binary program that waf builds in the same build process.
Here is a minimum example of the `wscript`:

```py
from waflib.Tools import waf_unit_test

def options(opt):
    opt.load("compiler_cxx python waf_unit_test")

def configure(cnf):
    cnf.load("compiler_cxx python waf_unit_test")


def build(bld):
    bld.add_post_fun(waf_unit_test.summary)
    bld.options.clear_failed_tests= True

    bld(features= "cxx cxxprogram",
        target= "foo",
        source= "foo.cpp")

    tg= bld(features= "test_scripts",
        test_scripts_source= "fooTest.py",
        test_scripts_template= "${PYTHON} ${SRC}")
    tg.post()
    tg.tasks[0].inputs.append(bld.path.find_or_declare("foo"))
```

I want to express that waf shall build the program `foo`.
Then,  if the program `foo` has changed since the last build run, the script `fooTest.py` shall check the execution of that program.  The `wscript` above works:

```
Waf: Entering directory `/home/x/tmp/exe_depend/build'
[1/3] Compiling foo.cpp
[2/3] Linking build/foo
[3/3] Processing utest: fooTest.py build/foo
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/x/tmp/exe_depend/build'
execution summary 
  tests that pass 1/1 
    /home/x/tmp/exe_depend/fooTest.py 
  tests that fail 0/1 
'build' finished successfully (0.054s)
```

In principle,  the `wscript` above fulfills my needs but it looks ugly as a hack and it seems wrong to fiddle with the task generator `tg`.  Does anyone of you knows a smooth solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's no many hooks in waf_unit_test.py. the best way is to extend it by making your own tool and putting your 2 lines of code in it. Something like that:

```py
# in file my_unit_test.py

def options(opt):
    opt.load("waf_unit_test") # we extend it, no need to recode

def configure(conf):
    conf.load("waf_unit_test") # we extend it, no need to recode

@feature('test_scripts')
@after_method('make_interpreted_test') # we execute after task creation
def process_test_scripts_dependencies(self):
    try:
        self.test_scripts_deps
    except AttributeError:
        return

    for task in self.tasks: # there can be many scripts
        task.set_inputs(self.to_nodes(self.test_scripts_deps))
```

Using it:

```py
def options(opt):
    opt.load("compiler_cxx python my_unit_test")

def configure(cnf):
    cnf.load("compiler_cxx python my_unit_test")


def build(bld):
    bld.add_post_fun(waf_unit_test.summary)
    bld.options.clear_failed_tests= True

    myprogram = "foo"

    bld(
        features = "cxx cxxprogram",
        target = myprogram,
        source = "foo.cpp",
    )

    bld(
        features = "test_scripts",
        test_scripts_deps = myprogram,
        test_scripts_source = "fooTest.py",
        test_scripts_template = "${PYTHON} ${SRC}",
    )
```

Of course, you can go further and rewrite something that fit your needs :)